# Why does the console print "null pointer assignment" after my array is printed?

Tags: c, assembly, malloc

my task was to write an assembly routine that use malloc of c and insert values to it from a pointer to function in asm, the array prints what it should and everything seems right exept after the numbers that theprogram prints, it adds "NULL POINTER ASSIGNMENT"

the c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern  int initarr (int** arr, int n, int (*initfunc)());

int getNum() 
{return (rand()%1000);}

void main()
{
int * arr, i, n, success;
printf("\nPlease enter the array size\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
success = initarr(&arr, n, getNum);   
if(!success) 
{
    printf("Memory Allocation Failed\n");
    return;
} 
printf("\nThe Numbers in the allocated array are:\n");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)   
    printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
}
```

the asm file:

```
;lab10.asm
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
.386
;extern  int initarr (int** arr, int n, int (*initfunc)())
;arr=BP+4   n=BP+6  function=BP+8
EXTRN _malloc : NEAR
PUBLIC _initarr
_initarr PROC NEAR 
PUSH BP;preserve BP
MOV BP,SP;let me see whats in the stack
PUSH SI;preserve SI
MOV SI,[BP+4];SI controls array
MOV CX,[BP+6];CX=n from declaration
MOV eAX,8;size of one byte=8
MUL CX;how many bytes to allocate
SUB eSP,eAX;size in bytes to allocate
PUSH eAX;preserve for later add to sp
PUSH eCX;for ussing malloc
CALL _malloc;return addres is in eAX
TEST eAX,eAX;checks if allocation succeded
POP eCX;pop CX for the loop
POP eAX;pop AX to add to SP
ADD eSP,eAX;for stack won't change
JZ BYE;if allocation went wrong and eAX is already 0
MOV [SI],eAX;sets SI to point at the array
MOV SI,[SI];set SI to the array
LOOPER:
PUSH CX;for ussing rand
CALL [BP+8];call function
POP CX;pop CX for the loop
MOV [SI],eAX
ADD SI,2
LOOP LOOPER
;end of loop    
MOV eAX,1;for the return value
BYE:
POP SI;restore SI
POP BP;restore BP
RET
_initarr ENDP
END
```

[image]

**__________________EDIT___________________**

for every size larger than 5 its work great
[image]

Comment: You need to check the value of n in initarr(&arr, n, getNum);

Comment: Look at the screenshot i added, i insert 4 and it prints 4 numbers

Comment: can u attach this `initarr(&arr, n, getNum)` function

Comment: initarr is an asm routine, getnum is a c function inside the c file above.
i forgot to add that it work great with n>5

Comment: The size in`success = initarr(&arr, n, getNum);  ` should be multiplied by the size of a single element : `success = initarr(&arr, n * sizeof *arr, getNum);  ` Second thought: Maybe that is where the `MUL CX;` is intended for ?

Comment: Is this 16 or 32-bit code? I believe using 32-bit registers in 16-bit mode may have side-effects. Since you are calling malloc - which may fail, and then checking EAX (32-bit register), it could be part of why it's not working right? And "size of one byte=8", surely you mean 1?

Comment: thats right, so i changhed it to

MOV eAX,16

so now its 2 bytes mul CX

Comment: More: `SUB eSP,eAX;size in bytes to allocate` - I guess that's supposed to be alloca(), which you then don't use, and just restor the stack pointer. `ADD eSP,eAX;for stack won't change` and
`JZ BYE;if allocation went wrong and eAX is already 0` - you are aware that the Z flag alters if you use ADD? This is just wrong everywhere. Try rewriting the code from scratch. I'm serious! [Yes, you can probably change a bit at a time to get it done, but it's going to take longer!]

Comment: 16 is _16 BYTES_ - 2 would be 2 bytes. Processors count in bytes (generally - some count in words and such, but really not many, and none that I'm aware of count in bits!)

Comment: you right, i need to input eAX 64 :X thank u very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

"null pointer assignment" message is displayed by some compilers clean up code on MSDOS platform. The clean up code checks if content of memory area around NULL ptr was changed (as there's no such thing as access violations in MSDOS). So, you need to check where your code can dereference NULL or other low offset. In the source below I can spot an error that does it:

```
CALL _malloc;return addres is in eAX
TEST eAX,eAX;checks if allocation succeded
POP eCX;pop CX for the loop
POP eAX;pop AX to add to SP
ADD eSP,eAX;for stack won't change
```

_malloc returns ptr in eAX that is overwritten 2 commands later by POP eAX (containig 8). Later you dereference it by `MOV [SI],eAX` that is the root cause of the error message.